# Why to calculate $\mathbf{weighted}$ average of the leaf node impurities in decision trees? Why not to just add entropies up without weights?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, cart, intuition, entropy

In decision trees why do we calculate weighted average of entropies of each leaf when we calculate the entropy of target variable given some feature? The question is: "Why is it **weighted average**? Why not to just add up entropies?" What bad could happen if we just added up all the entropies without multiplying them by weights?

I know that it's done because of different sizes of leaves, but don't understand how that weighted average is supposed to help. ***Why would we want to use weights?***

When we use weights we implicitly make big leaves' entropies more important when deciding what feature to use. But why would we want such behavior?